# Thymeleaf Email Template and ConversionService

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a spring mvc application where I am trying to render a date LocalDate into a string, for normal views it works but for emails it doesn't work and throws the following error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type [java.time.LocalDate]
>   to type [java.lang.String]

Code:

```
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;

@Service
public class EmailService {

    @Autowired
    private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    public String prepareTemplate() {
        // ...
        Context context = new Context();
        this.templateEngine.process(template, context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I debugged, found out that if we use a newly constructed Context it will create another instance of ConversionService instead of using the DefaultFormattingConversionService bean.

In thymeleaf spring's SpelVariableExpressionEvaulator we see the following code

```
        final Map<String,Object> contextVariables =
                computeExpressionObjects(configuration, processingContext);

        EvaluationContext baseEvaluationContext =
                (EvaluationContext) processingContext.getContext().getVariables().
                        get(ThymeleafEvaluationContext.THYMELEAF_EVALUATION_CONTEXT_CONTEXT_VARIABLE_NAME);

        if (baseEvaluationContext == null) {
            // Using a standard one as base: we are losing bean resolution and conversion service!!
            baseEvaluationContext = new StandardEvaluationContext();
        }
```

To solve this issue we have to make sure that our context contains the thymeleaf evaluation context initialized with the correct conversion service.

```
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@Service
public class EmailService {

    @Autowired
    private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    // Inject this
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    // Inject this
    @Autowired
    private ConversionService mvcConversionService;

    public String prepareTemplate() {
        // ...
        Context context = new Context();
        // Add the below two lines
        final ThymeleafEvaluationContext evaluationContext = new ThymeleafEvaluationContext(applicationContext, mvcConversionService);
        context.setVariable(ThymeleafEvaluationContext.THYMELEAF_EVALUATION_CONTEXT_CONTEXT_VARIABLE_NAME, evaluationContext);
        this.templateEngine.process(template, context);
    }
}
```

Problem solved.

Comment: I know this is pretty old but this just saved my mental sanity.